# Sql Server 2000: Return "true" or "false" based on any 1 of 25 columns being "true"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, bit-manipulation

I have to create a query that checks across several different columns, and if any of them have a 1, I want to return true.

Ideal output would be along the lines of:

ID:55
Name:John Doe
IsDealerType1:True
IsDealerType2:True
IsDealerType3:False
IsDealerType4:False
IsDealerType5:True

The problem is, instead of those 5 dealer columns, I have about 20 columns named 1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, etc.  If any of the "1" columns is true, then IsDealerType1 should be true.

I'm trying to avoid writing something in the VB.NET code to check each and every column, just because that sheer ugliness should be easy to avoid in SQL - if only I knew how to do it - but I'm not sure how to construct the query.  I've been trying stuff like...

```
SELECT id, 
      name, 
      (1a or 1b or 1c or 1d) as IsDealerType1, 
      (2a or 2b or 2c or 2d) as IsDealerType2 
where id = 55
```

... but obviously, I'm not doing it right.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like Russel's, but I'm gonna add this as well:

```
CASE WHEN 1 IN (1a,1b,1c,1d) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsDealerType1
```

Comment: Slick. Not my first thought, but I recently discovered this use of IN.

Comment: Excellent. For the benefit of others who may be searching, this technique also works on a WHERE clause on bit columns, but `|` and `OR` do not work. E.g. `WHERE 1 in (1a,1b,1c,1d)`

Answer (score 5):

CASE WHEN (1a + 1b + 1c + 1d) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsDealerType1

Comment: a lot nicer than     case 1a 
        when true 
        then true 
        else case 1b when true then true .... else false end etc.

Comment: I didn't know which one to check because they will all work - thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: In SQL Server the BIT type does not have an 'add' operator though, so 1a+1b would give error 8117 'Operand data type bit is invalid for add operator.'. This works only if 1a...1d is stored as numeric (tinyint, smallint, int etc), or a an aditonal cast on each 1a..1d column is required.

Answer (score 2):

Use the SQL [bitwise OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186714.aspx) operator. Avoids comparisons and casts.

Example: Joel's answers passes integer 1 or 0 to the client, where you'd arguably expect bit (boolean). Remus' answers needs casts and comparisons.

```
SELECT id, 
      name, 
      (1a | 1b | 1c | 1d) as IsDealerType1, 
      (2a | 2b | 2c | 2d) as IsDealerType2 
where id = 55
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL the BIT types cannot be used in boolean expressions (d'oh!!), they need to be compared with ints:

```
SELECT id, name, 
   cast(
    case when ([1a]=1 or [1b]=1 or [1c]=1 or [1d]=1) then 1 else 0 end
    as bit) as IsDealerType1,
    cast(case when ([2a]=1 or [2b]=1 or [2c]=1 or [2d]=1) then 1 else 0 end
    as bit) as IsDealerType2 
from [table]
where id = 55
```

Comment: ..but bit can use bitwise operators. Pls see my answer